# Resources in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, resources

I created ASP.NET MVC App and now I want to replace all literals with elements of my resources files.

I created App_GlobalResources folder in root directory and I added two files:

- Resources.en-US.resx
- Resources.es-ES.resx

[My app directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXSu2.png)

And in my views, I put this (for example):

```
<h1>@Resources.MyResource</h1>
```

But, always i see this error: *The name 'Resources' does not exist in the current context.*

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E74lp.png)

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Expand your `resources files` and open your `resource.Desinger,cs` file and see its `namespace`. Now use this `namespace` in your project to use `resources`.

Comment: Also, check if at least one file has enabled code generation and it set to Public.

Comment: I only can expandResources.en-US into Resources.en-US.designer.cs but I can't read anything...

Answer (score 0):

you need to define a single resource with multiple languages

in your case you will have to refer to the resources by name

@Resources.en-US.resx.MyResource
@Resources.en-ES.resx.MyResource

etc.

this is wrong approach

this is a good read

https://ruijarimba.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/asp-net-mvc-localization-generate-resource-files-and-localized-views-using-custom-templates/

and

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/778040/Beginners-Tutorial-on-Globalization-and-Localizati

Answer (score 0):

I follow the codeproject.com solution http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/778040/Beginners-Tutorial-on-Globalization-and-Localizati)

But when I set the culture (via controller by ajax query) nothing happens:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public JsonResult SetCulture(String cul) {

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cul);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cul);

    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

> cul parameter = "es-US"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I follow this solution http://www.ryadel.com/en/setup-a-multi-language-website-using-asp-net-mvc/#Set-up_a_Multi-Language_Route

I created "Resources" folder in root directory of my solution. And I added Global.resx and Global.en-EN.resx files

But, when I set culture:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(cul);
```

The Strings never changes... :(

Comment: I noticed that in my views, I can see

                <h1>@Resources.Global.Welcome</h1>
                <h1>@Resources.Global_en_EN.Welcome</h1>

You should not only see a "Global" ASP.NET object and select the file handle right resources?